# What are "Excess Defer Frames" on a show interface gix/x/x controller output?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, interface

I have a switch that is counting "output errors". A "show interface gi1/0/46 controller" shows up "2963657 Excess Defer frames" but I really can't find any documentation about "excess defer frames". 
Can some one tell me what kind of error this is and what circumstance can cause that?

Hardware is WS-C3650-48TS, Software 03.06.05E.
Do you need any more information?

Thanks in advance,

Flo

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/13203691/excess-defer-frames-or-xmit-errors - frames that are deferred can't be sent out the destination port right away and get queued. *Excess* deferred frames are those dropped when the output queue is overloaded.

There are several possible causes:

- the output port is linking at a slower speed than expected
- a stream from a faster link is funneled through a trunk group (usually, you can't successfully run a fullspeed 10G link through a 10x 1G trunk)
- your network architecture has a bottleneck and might need rethinking

Comment: Hi Zac, the switch is connected via 1G with one of our core-switches, not much traffic on the link:sh int gi1/0/46 human-readable | inc 30
  30 second input rate 1.34 mega-bits/sec , 936 pps
  30 second output rate 2.54 mega-bits/sec , 846 pps
both sides have negotiated 1g fullduplex... i have no clue anymore

Comment: Strange... The frame drops are continous? Are you using flow control somewhere? Multicast traffic? Do you experience any problems apart from the drop counter? That's 1000BASE-T? Have you tried another cable?

Comment: Hi Zac, what I've done so far: Changed the cable, changed the port (was 1/0/48, now 1/0/46. 1/0/47 is the second uplink but had no errors while active. So I guess it's not the packet forwarding engine who causes problems). I can see multicast traffic there, but I'm not sure where it comes from...need to ask the server guys. I know of a SQL-Server behind that switch...but sql shouldn't generate multicast traffic?...) Frame drops are continous. Flow control is deactivated on both devices. Auto-Qos is configured with its defaults....

Comment: And yes, it's a copper connection. Cable length is 2m. No patchpanel between. No errors on the other device.... I'm thinking of replacing the switch but I think that won't change anything because error is port-independent...

Comment: Multicast was just a wild guess - if it's not excessive, there shouldn't be a problem. I don't think it's the switch either, but am at a loss, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

*Excess Defer frames*: According to [Cisco documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3se/int_hw_components/command_reference/b_int_3se_3850_cr/b_int_3se_3850_cr_chapter_010.html) it is the number of frames that are not sent after the time exceeds the maximum-packet time.

It means that the port is under heavy load.

The device connected to the port is transmitting or receiving more traffic that can be handled by the port. Verify if the port is configured as half-duplex or full-duplex.

Comment: Hi jcbermu, thanks for your help. But the port is Full Duplex 1G, peer port is 1G fullduplex, too....Load isn't that heavy for 1g: #sh int gi1/0/46 human-readable | inc 30
  30 second input rate 1.34 mega-bits/sec , 936 pps
  30 second output rate 2.54 mega-bits/sec , 846 pps